# Struts2: Return null/key if mapping doesn't found in locale specific resource file

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, resourcebundle

I want to check a key mapping in locale specific resource bundle files ONLY in complete hierarchy and don't want to fall back to default `.properties` file.
Say I have resource bundle files `Text_fr.properties` and `Text.properties` and `global_fr.properties` and `global.properties`
I want that if I search a key in language 'fr', it should check in `*_fr.properties` files only and if no mapping found then don't return me default `*.properties` file value rather give me `null` or `key`

I have tried running this code segment but it didn't met my requirnment

```
    if(null != LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(key, getLocale())){
        return LocalizedTextUtil.findDefaultText(key, getLocale());
    }else{
         return defaultValue;
    }
```

I have tried other `LocalizedTextUtil.findText();` variants too.

Say I have following content in files

```
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------+
| Text_fr.properties | Text.properties | global_fr.properties | global.properties |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------+
| key.hi=Hi in fr    | key.hi=Hi in en | key.hi=fr            | key.hi=en         |
+--------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Now when I search `key.hi` with language `fr` I need to get strings `Hi in fr` or `fr` or if both mappings not found in `*_fr.properties` files I **do not** want it to return me either `Hi in en` or `en` rather just return me null or actual key.

Comment: Your requirement is clear. So is the answer to the question similar to your: you need to create a custom text provider, set it in struts.xml, override the getText methods with a custom implementation of the localizedtextutil, that behaves like you want and not like it does usually